# appending to string in getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone see the problem with this code?  When 'out' is returned, it has a value of "".  I have no idea why, perhaps it's something about the getJSON function im not aware of.

I'm trying to pass a URL to this function, have it perform getJSON on the URL, and add the results (which i'm also formatting) to a text string.  I want them all in one text string, so i can parse the string with regex.  Any help is appreciated, thanks!

```
function getSearch(url) {
var out = '';   // output variable

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    for(var i = 0; i < numResults; i++) {
        out += '<p class="hash_list">' + '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + data.results[i].from_user + '">' + data.results[i].from_user + '</a>: ' + data.results[i].text + '</p>';
    }
});

return out;
}
```

Comment: how is your JSON looks like ?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: @SLaks - any idea regarding a workaround?

Comment: what is `numResults` and what is its value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ajax is asynchronous, the code you have would return before the ajax request has finished. 
There are a few ways you can restructure your code.

You can pass in a callback function that gets executed once the request has finished.

```
function getSearch(url, callback) {
   $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     var out = '';    
     // btw what is numResults ?? 
     for(var i = 0; i < numResults; i++) {
        out += '<p class="hash_list">' + '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + data.results[i].from_user + '">' + data.results[i].from_user + '</a>: ' + data.results[i].text + '</p>';
     }
     if( typeof callback === 'function' ) callback( out ); 
   });
}
```

Then you would use the function like this.

```
getSearch('test.php', function(out){ 
   // here you can use the out variable 
});
```

Or you can use jquery deferreds to return a promise and pass the out variable as part of the argument when you resolve the deferred. Here's an example

```
function getSearch() 
{    
    var deferred = $.Deferred(); 
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
     var out = '';    
     // btw what is numResults ?? 
     for(var i = 0; i < numResults; i++) {
        out += '<p class="hash_list">' + '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + data.results[i].from_user + '">' + data.results[i].from_user + '</a>: ' + data.results[i].text + '</p>';
     }
     deferred.resolve( out ); // resolve the request and pass in the out argument.  
   });

    return deferred.promise(); // return a promise 
}


$.when( getSearch() ).then(function( out ){  // the out variable will get passed in
     console.log( out );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

AJAX is **asynchronous**.

You need to return the value using a callback function, the same way `getJSON` does:

```
function getSearch(url, callback) {
    $.getJSON(..., function() { 
        ...
        callback(...);
    });
}
```

Comment: could you provide an example? or a link to read more? brand new to this stuff, just started javascript a few days ago =X

Answer (score 1):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous.  This means that `out` is returned before the AJAX call finishes.

You cannot return anything from an AJAX call, you need to add all code that deals with `out` in the callback to `$.getJSON`.

I suggest passing a callback to your function.  Something like this:

```
function getSearch(url, callback) {
    var out = '';
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
        for(var i = 0; i < numResults; i++) {
            out += '<p class="hash_list">' + '<a href="http://www.twitter.com/' + data.results[i].from_user + '">' + data.results[i].from_user + '</a>: ' + data.results[i].text + '</p>';
        }
        if(typeof callback === 'function'){
            callback(out); // call your callback with data
        }
    });
}
```

Now, instead of expecting a return value from `getSearch`, you send it a callback.

```
getSearch('http://example.com/myurl', function(data){
    // this function will get called sometime in the future,
    // once $.getJSON is done, "data" will be the "out" from the AJAX call
});
```